# Качество выводимого в picturebox изображения

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

Есть битмап размером 100x100 пикселей, он растягивается и отображается в pictureBox формы,и выглядит это следующим образом (пискели мыльные, нету четкости изображения)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но при этом, если сохранить битмап как изображение и открыть его в программе windows для просмотра фото, растянув, то мы увидим следующую картину 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На втором скриншоте чёткость заметно выше, с чем это может быть связано?
И как добиться такой же четкости в pictureBox  на форме?

Comment: Покажите код, как именно вы растягиваете битмап. И хорошо бы приложить оригинальное изображение.

Comment: @Alexander битмап никак не растягиваю,он сам растягивается посредством SizeMode.Zoom у pictureBox

Comment: Поменяйте InterpolationMode. `Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;`

Comment: Да, изменение режима интерполяции поможет. Но при этом нужно вручную отрисовывать изображение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-бы изображение не выглядело размитым при масштабировании, Вам нужно изменить режим [интерполяции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-interpolation-mode-to-control-image-quality-during-scaling): `Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;`

Можно сделать это вручную, при отрисовке изображения:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
}
```

или создать наследника `PictureBox`-а и переопределить `OnPaint`:

```
public class CustomPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    private System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode interpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

    public System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode InterpolationMode 
    {
       get => interpolationMode;
       set
       {
          interpolationMode = value;
          this.Invalidate(); //перерисовываем
       }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
       pe.Graphics.InterpolationMode = interpolationMode;
       base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

Comment: с наследником хороший вариант, особенно если режим интерполяции вынести во внешнее свойство.

Comment: Да, использовать наследника с переопределенным `OnPaint` проще всего.

Comment: @rdorn, хорошая идея, дополнил.

Comment: Обидно только что он `NearestNeighbor` у них как-то с [перекосом](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDdr1.png) работает, а лучше ни чего нет. Исходное изображение 16*16, может на более крупных не так заметно будет.